# how to correctly use tf.function with a TensorFlow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use TF Datasets with a @tf.function to perform some preprocessing on a directory of images. Inside the *tf* function the image file is read as a RAW string tensor and I'm trying to take a slice from that tensor. The slice, the first 13 characters, represent info about .ppm images (header). I get an error: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'Slice' (op: 'Slice') with input shapes: [], [1], [1]`. Initially I was trying to directly slice the .numpy() attribute of the tensor (`filepath` input parameter to the *tf* function), but I think it is semantically wrong to do this inside a *tf* function. It also didn't work as the `filepath` input tensor does not have a numpy() attribute (I don't understand why??). Outside of the *tf* function, e.g. in a jupyter notebook cell, I can iterate over the dataset and get individual items which have a numpy attribute and do a slice and all subsequent processing on it just fine. I do realize there may be a gap in my understanding of how TF works (I am using TF 2.0), so I hope someone can clarify what I missed in my readings. The purpose of the *tf* function is convert the ppm images to png, so there is a side effect of this function, but I did not get that far to find out if this is possible to do.

Here's the code:

```
@tf.function
def ppm_to_png(filepath):
    ppm_bytes = tf.io.read_file(filepath) #.numpy()
    bytes_header = tf.slice(ppm_bytes, [0], [13])
    # bytes_header = ppm_bytes[:13].eval()  # this did not work either with similar error msg
    .
    .
    .
```

```
import glob

files = glob.glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '00000/*.ppm'))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
png_filepaths = dataset.map(ppm_to_png, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate string values in TF, have a look at the [tf.strings namespace](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/strings).

In this case, you can use `tf.strings.substr`:

```
@tf.function
def ppm_to_png(filepath):
  ppm_bytes = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
  bytes_header = tf.strings.substr(ppm_bytes, 0, 13)
  tf.print(bytes_header)
```

`tf.slice` only operates on the Tensor objects, and doesn't work on their elements. Here, `ppm_bytes` is a scalar Tensor containing a single element of type `tf.string`, and whose value is the entire string contents of the file. So when you call `tf.slice`, it only looks at the scalar bit, and is not smart enough to realize that you actually want to take a slice of that element instead.

Comment: substr worked, but I still get a tensor that has no numpy attribute. I need the content of the header tensor so I can decode it. The header contains characters and integers. How do I get those values out of the tensor (bytes_header)? Also, why does the code work in python and not when I use it with a TF dataset? I thought eager execution is default now, so TF code is more pythonic... I don't get why the tensors inside ppm_to_png() have no numpy attribute that I can use inside the function??

Comment: numpy() is not available in tf.function. It is not obvious, but datasets always use tf.function even in eager execution. To get the numpy value and run arbitrary python, you should use [py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) - that is, write a separate function, wrap that with py_function and call that from the function you give to the dataset.

Comment: That said, I recommend that you separately convert your images to png and then use [tf.io.decode_image](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image)